# Como fazer um loop/rotina para a função write.fst()?

Tags: r, loop, for

Tenho os seguinte arquivos no meu diretório de trabalho:

```
Dados_1.fst
Dados_2.fst
Dados_3.fst
Dados_4.fst
...
Dados_10.fst
```

O arquivo Dados_x.fst (onde x vai de 1 a 10)tem as colunas CODIGO, INSCRICAO, RESPOSTAS_A, RESPOSTAS_B

Daí crio os seguintes data frames:

```
df.1 <- select(filter(read.fst("Dados_1.fst"), CODIGO ==     
10102),INSCRICAO,RESPOSTAS_A,RESPOSTAS_B)
df.2 <- select(filter(read.fst("Dados_2.fst"), CODIGO ==
10102),INSCRICAO,RESPOSTAS_A,RESPOSTAS_B)
df.3 <- select(filter(read.fst("Dados_3.fst"), CODIGO == 
10102),INSCRICAO,RESPOSTAS_A,RESPOSTAS_B)
...
df.10 <- select(filter(read.fst("Dados_10.fst"), CODIGO == 
10102),INSCRICAO,RESPOSTAS_A,RESPOSTAS_B)
```

**Gostaria de fazer um loop de tal forma que não precisasse escrever o código acima 10 vezes.**

Tentei seguir o caminho abaixo, mas sem sucesso

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
paste("df",i, sep =".") <- select(filter(read.fst(paste(paste("Dados",i,sep="_"),"fst",sep =".")), 
CODIGO == 10102),INSCRICAO,RESPOSTAS_A,RESPOSTAS_B)
 }
```

Até+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer o que quer, o melhor é utilizar o `lapply` aplicando a cada elemento do vetor `Dados` a função anónima que lê os ficheiros `fl`.
O valor do `lapply` é um objeto de classe `list`, e cada tabela será um membro dessa lista. Isso é muito melhor do que ter 10 tabelas no `GlobalEnv`.

```
Dados <- list.files(pattern = "Dados_[[:digit:]]+\\.fst")

df_list <- lapply(Dados, function(fl){
    select(filter(read.fst(fl), CODIGO == 10102), INSCRICAO, RESPOSTAS_A, RESPOSTAS_B)
})

names(df_list) <- paste("df", seq_along(Dados), sep = ".")

df_list$df.1         # primeira tabela
df_list[["df.1"]]    # a mesma tabela, repare que "df.1" é uma string
df_list[[1]]         # a mesma tabela
```

Comment: Funcionou bem ! Obrigado ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar as variáveis dinamicamente e para isso R pode utilizar [*assign*](https://developer.r-project.org/NotesOnGet.html).

```
x = 1:10
for (i in 1:10)
{
    assign(paste("df", i, sep="."), x[i]) = select(filter(read.fst(paste(paste("Dados",i,sep="_"),"fst",sep =".")), 
CODIGO == 10102),INSCRICAO,RESPOSTAS_A,RESPOSTAS_B)
}
```

---

**Fontes**

Uso de assign num for loop: [StackOveflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081982/how-to-assign-values-to-dynamic-names-variables-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Está dando esse erro _Error in assign(paste("df", i, sep = "."), x[i]) = select(filter(read.fst(paste(paste("Dados",  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object_
Será que estou fazendo alguma coisa errada?